# Let L and M be finite dimensional linear spaces over the field F. Prove that $ \dim L/L_{0}= \dim M/M_{0}$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L$ and $M$ be finite dimensional linear spaces over the field $F$ and let $g : L \times M \to F$ be a bilinear mapping. We shall call the set
$L_{0} = \{l ∈ L : g(l, m) = 0\text{ for all }m ∈ M\}$
the left kernel of $g$ and the set
$M_{0} = \{m ∈ M : g(l, m) = 0\text{ for all }l ∈ L\}$
the right kernel of $g$. Prove that $ \dim L/L_{0} = \dim M/M_{0}$.

Comment: Row rank equals column rank?

Comment: Yes, row rank of Gram matrix of bilinear form equals the column rank of Gram matrix.

Comment: Turn that into a proof!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can appreciate a “matrix free” proof.

Define $\varphi\colon L\to (M/M_0)^*$ by
$$
\varphi(x)\colon y+M_0\mapsto g(x,y)
$$
(where $(M/M_0)^*$ is the dual space to $M/M_0$). For every $x\in L$, the linear form $\varphi(x)$ is well defined, because if $y\in M_0$, then $g(x,y)=0$. The map $\varphi$ is clearly linear.

The kernel of $\varphi$ is precisely $L_0$, hence $\dim(L/L_0)\le\dim(M/M_0)^*=\dim(M/M_0)$.

By symmetry, also the reverse inequality holds.